# How to kill a session on browser close in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, cookies, django-views

I am using Python- Django for my application. I want to kill the session when a user close his browser and want to store that session killing or browser closing time in database.
Django sessions provide mechanism to expire session when a user close browser by deleting session cookie from the browser by setting

```
 SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=True
```

in settings.py file. it deletes session cookie from user browser. can I get this event on back end or in django? or how can I pass a message to Django server by ajax that the browser has been closed and session cookie has been deleted.   Tell me if it is possible by django or how can it be done using javascript

Answer (score 1):

In order to make an ajax call before unload I am afraid you will end showing an annoying alert box to the user as its what the event expects:

```
Date.prototype.timeNow = function(){
     return ((this.getHours() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getHours() +":"+ ((this.getMinutes() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getMinutes() +":"+ ((this.getSeconds() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getSeconds();
};

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var timeNow = new Date().timeNow(); 
    $.post( "api/closingTime", { "closingTime": timeNow } );
    return "Thanks for your visit";
});
```

which is also a little problematic as if the user decides to click to stay on the page the post request still goes ahead

Comment: Thank you XGreen , SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=True. using this method in Django, cookie is deleted automatically from browser when it is closed. I just wanted to send an ajax request to the Django sever so that i get the cuurent time when request came and store that time to database.

Comment: Thanx Xgreen, i didn't tried your method because I tried this one window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 alert("hey u r leaving this site")
    return "Hey, you're leaving the site. Bye!";
}; 
but i gives me alert or call the method each time even when i click on a link . means when a url change this method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a signal like this

```
  from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out


  def do_stuff(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
      whatever...

  user_logged_out.connect(do_stuff)
```

See django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals and here http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: This signal only works if user does logout . but not if he close the browser without logging out